# Set of m integers from an array of size n

Tags: java, arrays, random, collections, set

**Write a method to randomly generate a set of m integers from an array of size n. Each element must have equal probability of being chosen.**

This is a fairly well known question - featured in multiple books and interviews - but either I am not reading the question correctly, or to me the requirements of this question cannot actually all be fulfilled at the same time in Java.

Let's say have an array of size n=3

**Integer[] ar = {1,1,5}**

if w chose **m=2** for our randomly generated set, I don't see how we can guarantee an equal probability for each element to be chosen.

In other words, asking for a Java set of 2 integers from the given array of size 3 makes it impossible to ensure an equal probability for each element. To illustrate, if we call the [0] a, [1] b, [2] c, then the all the 2 element combinations chosen at random, with removal, will look like this:

1. ab
2. ba
3. ac
4. bc
5. ca
6. cb

Since choices 1) and 2) would automatically invalidate a unique element requirement of a set in Java, in this particular situation element 'c' i.e. number **5** will always end up with a probability of 100% if we are to end up with a set of 2 elements.

I guess it is even easier to illustrate this issue if the array contains only duplicates i.e. {1,1,1}, and then a set of m=2 integers would simply be impossible.

Is there something I am misreading or misinterpreting with regards to this question.

Comment: To be honest, your question is unclear even though you tried your best to explain it. Can you try again? On another note, maybe they didn't mean a `Set<E>`, but just a set in the mathematical sense.

Comment: well if it is a Set( if you want in the mathematical sence) then it cannot cointain one element twice. It can however contain two distinct elements representing the same integer.

Comment: @Gendarme: my whole issue is trying to answer the question as written (I did not make or edit the question, and it is copied exactly word for word as written in more than one book on the subject). Read it as any person might read it on an examination, where the proctor cannot provide clarification. My whole problem with these types of questions is that it can in theory be testing two very different things: knowledge of data structures (shuffling algorithm) OR understanding of Java Collections (Set contains unique, unsorted values only)

Comment: @kai mathematically yes, but unless I am missing something this is not possible in Java. A HashSet<Object> , a sorted TreeSet etc. will compare any item for addition against items already present. Trimming the original array to size of unique elements only seems logical, but then the element's equal probability condition gets violated.

Comment: My point was: if you have to make the elemebts "unique" you have violated the constraint, that it is a set. (a set is ignorant of duplicates). So {1,1,1} == {1} == {1,1} and {1} + {1} = {1}

Comment: That said, the first step is to define what an "element" is. In the question it is mixed up: a) element of the array(that is the object at an index), b) element of the set(that is an element of the set) c) a distinct value(that is 1, 2, 3...). With that the question might become easier("name and conquer").

Comment: The best solution to such a question is to add the constraint that the array must not contain duplicates, provide a solution under that premise and document the fact that this constraint is necessary, as otherwise, no solution is possible.